# How to use System.Web.Caching in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, asp.net-4.5

I have a class that looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Caching;

public static class MyCache
{
    private static string cacheKey = "mykey";

    public static Dictionary<string, bool> GetCacheValue(bool bypassCache)
    {
        var settings = Cache[cacheKey] as Dictionary<string, bool>; // error on this line

        // ...etc...

        return settings
    }
}
```

the problem I'm having is that this wont compile. The compiler says `Cache` can't be used the way I'm doing it. Here's the message:

```
'System.Web.Caching.Cache' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

This perplexes me. I've googled the ASP.NET Cache API and have found many examples of `Cache` being used this way. Here's one of those examples:

```
// http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100902-1.aspx
value = Cache("key")

      - or -

value = Cache.Get("key")
```

When I try using `Cache.Get()` I get another error saying that it's not a static method.

Evidently I need to initialize an instance of `Cache`. Is this the correct way to use this API? A follow-up question is, does cached information persist across instances?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `HttpRuntime.Cache` to get to `Cache` instance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`System.Web.Caching.Cache` is a class - you see people using a property named `Cache` that is an *instance* of `System.Web.Caching.Cache`.  If you're using it outside of a class that provides you with the `Cache` property, access it using `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache`:

```
var settings = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] as Dictionary<string, bool>;
```

Comment: Awesome. I love it when there is a simple explanation!